# How do I extract certain elements from this webscraped HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's the HTML I have webscraped. How do I extract the text called "Code I want to Extract" and then save this as a string "author"? Thanks in advance!

```html
<a class="lead-author-profile-link" href="https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=2994282" target="_blank" title="View other papers by this author"><span>Code I want to Extract</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-gizmo-navigate-right"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it:

```
html_doc="""
<a class="lead-author-profile-link" href="https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=2994282" target="_blank" title="View other papers by this author"><span>Code I want to Extract</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-gizmo-navigate-right"></i></a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
author = soup.find('a').text
print(author)
```

Output will be:

```
Code I want to Extract
```